# Open database with ALL discovered stars and their parameters?

Tags: star, resource-request, raw-data

I am looking for an open database, obligatory an up-to-dated one, which includes **all** discovered stars and their parameters.

Comment: It's not ALL known stars, but going through this might be a good start: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/where-can-i-find-a-catalog-of-all-stars-in-the-milky-way

Comment: See GAIA in the answer to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488

Comment: The answer is no. Your best bet if you know where the star is (or what its name is), is to interrogate SIMBAD  http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/

Answer (score 1):

As @ProfRob already stated, there is no **single** star database with **all** parameters. Here are some resources:

- [SIMBAD Astronomical Database](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/)
- [GAIA Archive](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/) *"providing astrometry, photometry, and spectroscopy of more than 1000 million stars in the Milky Way."*

A **[helpful and extensive collection of online resources](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13489/37191)** is collected as community wiki answer to the question [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/)